# Apple developer: How to generate App Id

Tags: app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program, app-id

I have a app for mobile that is build using [AppPresser](https://apppresser.com/) plugin of WordPress. To generate **apk** or **ipa** file I am using [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com) site that provide facility to upload zip folder with source code and returns the `.apk` and `.ipa` files for Android and Apple.

Now, I am getting `.apk` file properly for Android but to get `.ipa` file, this phonegap require the apple account integrated with it.

So, to integrate this account I have generated `.p12` file and now trying to get `provisioning profile` file. I am on the page of [Register an App ID](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle/create) of apple and get stuck at first field of `Name`. Please check below image.

[image: Apple Registering App ID]

First part of `name` is Team Id and second part is Bundle ID. I have googled and checked many docs. Found how to get bundle Id. It can be get from emulator of project on MAC machine.

But my problem is that, I am not developing project through MAC, so how would I get this bundle ID to complete this field with correct value ?

Please help.

Comment: in name just give a simple name without special characters .. its not asking for bundle id ....

Comment: @El Captain, can you please provide example here in this case?

Comment: just use flasco as a name and in bundle id provide your application bundle id ... thats it

Comment: Ahh.. Yes, working fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: you can set any name you want without special character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your app name their .

eg :- Whatsapp.

Don't add bundle id in the name of the app.